# Django: How to bind two fields in two models, i.e. make them exactly the same?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Here I have a **User** model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    plate_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
```

and a **Vehicle** model:

```
class Vehicle(models.Model):
    plate_number = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
```

I do not think my design is correct, because plate_number in Vehicle model is not CharField but User in this way.

How to make two **plate_number** exactly the same in two models?

The logic is, a User **MAY NOT** have a plate_number but a vehicle **MUST HAVE** a same plate_number existing in User model, a user can have **AT MOST ONE** vehicle and a vehicle only belongs to one User, and I would like either field change, then the counterpart field makes the same change automatically.

Is this possible? How about

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    vehicle = models.OneToOneField('ride.Vehicle', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL())
```

and

```
class Vehicle(models.Model):
    plate_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, blank=False, null=False)
```

Will this work?

Comment: OneToOneField can be a primary_key?

Comment: I think there is a problem in your logic. `The logic is, a User MAY NOT have a plate_number but a vehicle MUST HAVE a same plate_number existing in User model`. If user don't have any plate_number then how Vehicle have same plate_number?

Comment: @ManzurulHoqueRumi thanks for the reply！If all users do not have a specific plate_number，then vehicle class does not have this specific plate_number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any point of having duplicate plate numbers. As you have defined a [OneToOne](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/) relationship between user and Vehicle, means one user can only have one Vehicle. So, I think its best you should keep both plate number and OneToOne connection in Vehicle model class, like this:

```
class Vehicle(models.Model):
    plate_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    user= models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name="vehicle")
```

Here I have defined `related_name` in Vehicle model.

So in this setup a user can have one plate number only as he has connection to one vehicle. And when accessing that data you can simply get it by:

```
user = User.objects.first()
user.vehicle # Vehicle object
user.vehicle.plate_number # plate number
```

Comment: Thank you! I have figured out!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done like this

User Model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    plate_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
```

Vehicle Model:

```
class Vehicle(models.Model):
    plate_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, blank=False, null=False)
    user= models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

So when you are saving vehicle check user with this plate number exists then save the user in vehicle if not then user is null and save plate number in char field.